# Is a promotion supposed to be a new position?

Tags: support, developer-story

Filling my developer story, I wonder how to properly handle promotion case.

If I joined a company as a software engineer, and over time I get promoted to a senior position, would it be correct now to set my whole position for this company in the developer story to be a senior, or it's supposed to be a new entry in it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Developer Story is an alternative to traditional resumes so you should handle it the same way and make a new entry. You don't want to say that you've been at your new senior position for the entire time you've been at the company.

Answer (score 5):

I would say to treat the promotion as a new position **only if your role changed**. In my experience people will look at your work history and decide for themselves just how "senior" you are. They don't care when your title changed.

Comment: What if you work for an outsource company and your role actually changes many time per year without any title change?

Comment: That's hard. Personally I would probably break them up in a way that I thought benefits me. No one wants to read a resume where you change roles ever three months, and you get to put your best foot forward. Don't lie, but you get to present the information in a way that benefits everyone involved.